# Getting "server closed the connection" error for mysql module from node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, database-connection

I am trying to query a table from node.js. Below is my code.But I get the error like "server closed the connection". Not sure what blunder mistake I am doing.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "10.90.103.4",
  user: "someuser",
  password: "********",
  database: "db",
  port: 1521
});

console.log("---------------------------");
console.log(con);
console.log("---------------------------");


con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  con.query("select * from CLE_EXCEPTIONRECORD where CORRELATIONID='983b2f58-e0eb-49cb-b76c-9b8107de3edc'", function (err, result, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

But I get the below error. Please suggest me to get success response.

```
Connection {
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _eventsCount: 0,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  config:
   ConnectionConfig {
     host: '10.90.103.4',
     port: 1521,
     localAddress: undefined,
     socketPath: undefined,
     user: 'THREE_SDEV_EXP_USER',
     password: 'PA55WORD',
     database: 'CITA',
     connectTimeout: 10000,
     insecureAuth: false,
     supportBigNumbers: false,
     bigNumberStrings: false,
     dateStrings: false,
     debug: undefined,
     trace: true,
     stringifyObjects: false,
     timezone: 'local',
     flags: '',
     queryFormat: undefined,
     pool: undefined,
     ssl: false,
     multipleStatements: false,
     typeCast: true,
     maxPacketSize: 0,
     charsetNumber: 33,
     clientFlags: 455631 },
  _socket: undefined,
  _protocol:
   Protocol {
     domain: null,
     _events: {},
     _eventsCount: 0,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     readable: true,
     writable: true,
     _config:
      ConnectionConfig {
        host: '10.90.103.4',
        port: 1521,
        localAddress: undefined,
        socketPath: undefined,
        user: 'THREE_SDEV_EXP_USER',
        password: 'PA55WORD',
        database: 'CITA',
        connectTimeout: 10000,
        insecureAuth: false,
        supportBigNumbers: false,
        bigNumberStrings: false,
        dateStrings: false,
        debug: undefined,
        trace: true,
        stringifyObjects: false,
        timezone: 'local',
        flags: '',
        queryFormat: undefined,
        pool: undefined,
        ssl: false,
        multipleStatements: false,
        typeCast: true,
        maxPacketSize: 0,
        charsetNumber: 33,
        clientFlags: 455631 },
     _connection: [Circular],
     _callback: null,
     _fatalError: null,
     _quitSequence: null,
     _handshake: false,
     _handshaked: false,
     _ended: false,
     _destroyed: false,
     _queue: [],
     _handshakeInitializationPacket: null,
     _parser:
      Parser {
        _supportBigNumbers: false,
        _buffer: <Buffer >,
        _nextBuffers: [Object],
        _longPacketBuffers: [Object],
        _offset: 0,
        _packetEnd: null,
        _packetHeader: null,
        _packetOffset: null,
        _onError: [Function: bound handleParserError],
        _onPacket: [Function: bound ],
        _nextPacketNumber: 0,
        _encoding: 'utf-8',
        _paused: false } },
  _connectCalled: false,
  state: 'disconnected',
  threadId: null }
---------------------------
F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:112
  var err = new Error('Connection lost: The server closed the connection.');
            ^
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
    at Protocol.end (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Pro
tocol.js:112:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connec
tion.js:97:28)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connec
tion.js:502:10)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
    at Protocol._enqueue (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protoco
l\Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\protoc
ol\Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (F:\johny\node_from_home\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connec
tion.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\johny\node_from_home\testselenium_old.js:16:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)

F:\johny\node_from_home>
```

Below is my actual table. When I query from putty I am able to get response.

[image]

Comment: You are throwing the error on two places in your code. Are you sure it's the query that throws the error and not the connect?

Comment: it is the connect which throws the error. Actually error in connection

Comment: That probably means the connection can't be made because the server closed the connection upon connecting. Check if you can reach it using telnet on the designated port and if it actually responds with the mysql protocol (some gibberish that ends with "mysql_native_password")

Comment: Telnet worked fine (telnet 10.90.103.4 1521). I even queried from putty.Also created new outbound rule for this port in firewall. Still getting the same issue. Is this because of node version or something?